# how to input a BigInteger type in java

Tags: java

when I tried to get an input of type Integer, what I only needed to do was the code below.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int N = sc.nextInt();
```

but when it comes to BigInteger, 
I don't know what to do. What can I do to read a BigInteger Type input from the user?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
BigInteger bi = sc.nextBigInteger();
```

Reference: [Scanner#nextBigInteger](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextBigInteger%28%29)

Answer (score 3):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
BigInteger b = new BigInteger(sc.next());
```

There is also:

```
BigInteger b = sc.nextBigInteger();
```

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
Scanner.nextBigInteger()
```

But I have to recommend that you read the documentation rather than ask this question. You harm yourself by not researching.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you prepare to catch an exception from the BigInteger - if the scanner fails to find a string you might get a BigInteger with non integer characters and it'll throw an exception.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(fileOrOther);
try{
     BigInteger bigint = scanner.nextBigInteger();
} catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
//handle Code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the BigInteger package:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
```

Include this package and code below:-

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
BigInteger=sc.nextBigInteger();
```